# Azure queues getMessages method in sdk not working as expected

Tags: node.js, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I have created a queue in Azure Queue and enqueued two items in it. Using the nodejs sdk, i create a timer that executes every 5 secs and calls:

```
azure.createQueueService("precondevqueues", "<key>").getMessages(queueName, {numOfMessages : 1, visibilityTimeout: 1 }, callback)
```

I expect that the same message of the two in the queue to show up after every 5 secs but that does not seem to be the case. The output of this call alternates between the two messages.

This should not be the case since visibilityTimeout is set to 1 and hence, after 1 second, the message dequeued in the first call should be visible again before the next getMessage call is made.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179363.aspx), FIFO ordering is not guaranteed. So it may be the case, that most of the time messages are fetched in FIFO order, but that is not guaranteed and Azure can give you the messages in the order which is best for their implementation.

> Messages are generally added to the end of the queue and retrieved
>   from the front of the queue, although first in, first out (FIFO)
>   behavior is not guaranteed.

Comment: Well i am seeing the behavior every time. It seems as if the getMessages actually updates the entry pushes it to the back of the queue.

Comment: Yea that's possible and it is absolutely fine with the statement in their documentation

Comment: I tried with 3 items and then 4 and it behaves as if getMessages takes the item out and then enqueues it back at the tail. So if you enqueue a,b,c and d then every few interval you do a getMessage (with visibility timeout less than the interval), you basically cycle through a->b->c->d

Comment: Again, this is absolutely fine with their documentation as they make no guarantees about the ordering. It could be a->b->c->d or b->a->c->d. It is no misbehavior as no ordering is guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Aha my mistake! I again read the getMessages documentation very carefully and realize that getMessages dequeues the message but retains a invisible copy **outside of the queue**. If the message processor does not delete the message before the visibility timeout expires, the copy is re-enqueued in the message and therefore they go to the end of the queue.